# Logging syncronous command unrecognized

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-ios, cisco-commands

I have a Cisco SG300-10 with software version 1.3.7.18. The switch is configured as a layer 3 device. I'm trying to stop the log message from interfering with my commands. I have tried to type logging synchronous in line mode. What's also odd is that the line mode is not the typical "line console 0" command. It's just "line console". It is so difficult to google for cisco command issues because things that are simple like just being in the wrong mode are assumed to be known already and never declared in solutions.

Console connection is RS-232(on switch) to RS-232(on laptop)

The first question among many, I suppose, is why is this an unrecognized command? What other command could be available to achieve the same behavior? Is the software version the reason this command is not available? Is it the mode I'm in? Is it because it's configured as a layer 3 switch? Is it because it's a RS-232 to RS-232 console connection rather than a RJ-45 rollover to RS-232?

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: The first question among many, I suppose, is why is this an unrecognized command? What other command could be available to achieve the same behavior? Is the software version the reason this command is not available? Is it the mode I'm in? Is it because it's configured as a layer 3 switch? Is it because it's a RS-232 to RS-232 console connection rather than a RJ-45 rollover to RS-232?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SG300 runs a different OS than "standard" IOS, and the `logging synchronous` command is not available in any released version.  It has nothing to do with the way you're connected or the configuration.

As to "why," only the Cisco developers can answer that.

Comment: Thank you sir. Is there an alternative command on the SG300 that will achieve the same results?

Comment: You can see for yourself [here.](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/csbms/sf30x_sg30x/administration_guide/CLI_Nikola300_1_3_7.pdf)